# variance tends to zero implies uniformly bounded by a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance

Given random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ with $E(X_n)  =0$ and $Var(X_n)\to 0$ does it follow that 
$X_n$ is uniformly bounded by a random variable $X$, i.e.,

$P(|X_n| > t) \leq P(|X|>t) \,\,\forall n$ for any $t$?

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make much sense: all probabilities are bounded by 1.
Namely, taking $X = \infty$ a.s. yields $\mathbb{P}(|X| > t) = 1$ for all $0 \leq t < \infty$.

Regardless, it might be helpful point out that [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) yields
$$
\mathbb{P}(\left|X_{n}\right|>t)=\mathbb{P}(\left|X_{n}-\mathbb{E}X_n\right|>t)\leq\text{Var}(X_{n})/t^{2}.
$$
Maybe the above bound is more useful for whatever you are trying to do?